# How to share methods from other class

Tags: objective-c, oop

I tried to use protocol, but it needs to implement "makeMeDraggable" method for each 2 classes with the same content. I wish not to implement in each 2 classes and inherit implementation from Shared Class. How do I achieve it?

Code:

```
//--(.h)--//

@interface SharedClass : UIView;
-(void) makeMeDraggable
@end

@interface DraggableUITextView: UITextView
@end

@interface DraggableUIImageView : UIImageView
@end

@implementaion SharedClass
-(void) makeMeDraggable {
  //some code
}
@end

@implementation DraggableUITextView
@end

@implementation DraggableUIImageView 
@end

//--(.m)--//

TextView *textView = [DraggableUITextView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
[textView makeMeDraggable];

ImageView *imageView = [DraggableUIImageView imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
[imageView makeMeDraggable];
```

I want to **avoid** below:

```
@interface DraggableTextView: UITextView;
-(void) makeMeDraggable
@end

@interface DraggableUIImageView : UIImageView
-(void) makeMeDraggable
@end

@implementation DraggableUITextView
-(void) makeMeDraggable {
  //same code...
}
@end

@implementation DraggableUIImageView 
-(void) makeMeDraggable {
  //same code...
}
@end
```

Comment: if you want only shared methods why not use a uiview category instead of inheritance

Comment: You can even make your category check for subclasses that should do the desired behavior or not, making it effectively only apply to classes you want it to.

Comment: Thanks, I am a beginner about object-c and I didn't know about category. Category check is so useful for me. My project has a lot more UIView classes, is extending common superclass with category OK for performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `UIView` category and write the function there rather than `SharedView`.Like:

```
@interface UIView (UIViewCategory)
-(void) makeMeDraggable;
@end


@implementaion UIView (UIViewCategory)
-(void) makeMeDraggable {
  //some code
}
@end
```

Now you can use `makeMeDraggable` method with every object inherited from `UIView` class.

Answer (score 1):

Create a category over UIView with the method makeMeDraggable and you will be able to use it on both UITextView and UIImageView objects.

Comment: Thanks! I googled category...that's the answer. I found "Composition" at the same time but doesn't it work for this case?

Comment: Object composition is not the cleaner solution in this case... go for the simplest: the category :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is with a [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on a common superclass, in your case, `UIView`.

The Category extends its class with new methods, which are then available like ordinary methods to all subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for specific answer! Everyone says "Category" lol Is that the only solution?

Comment: Basically, yes. There is no real multiple inheritance of implementations in Objective-C. Categories are not hard to learn, but there are a few things you need to be careful about: If you define a method in a category, it may collide with future methods Apple may add to the class, so give your category methods prefixes (like for class names).